# Сделал "движок" сайта,но в разных локальных серверах ведет себя по-разному

Tags: mysql

два месяца назад задумал делать типа новостной сайт, и вот — движок готов (крайне простой: добавляет, удаляет, редактирует, через обычные textarea без чужих редакторов платных/бесплатных)

Не знаю, можно ли его уже выставлять, так как если открывать его на OPENSERVER, то работает нормально (с кирилицей и отображением записей все норм), а вот в неком редакторе если запускать его, он не отображает русские слова и может не отобразить введенную строку.

От чего это зависит? База данных и таблицы одни и те же. Была б проблема с кодом то думаю было б и в африке отображение проблемное, а тут когда как. Не будет ли проблем когда загрузить его на реальный сервер? На что обратить внимание?

Comment: ИМХО, 99% проблемы в кодировке, я надеюсь везде используется utf-8 без bom (кодировка файлов, кодировка соединения, кодировка базы)? Только не говорите про windows-1251 - вопрос можно сразу удалять.